# Is there any easy conversion between common wildcards (e.g. * and ?) and javascript regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

`*` and `?` are the easiest for non-programmers to understand, with respect to wildcards; in this case, multiple characters and a single character wildcards, respectively.

If I receive a string, where a `"?"` could appear in any position of the string (e.g. "sing?" or "spo?ls"), how can I convert the string into a javascript regexp which I then compare against a dictionary list?  In the case of `"spo?ls"`, I would expect to match "spools", "spoils", etc.

Ditto for use of `"*"`.  Thanks.

Sorry if I was not clear: When I meant common wildcards, common to other environments, not Javascript: so, yes, "?" equals any single character [a-z] and "*" equals one or more characters [a-z].  In the case of "*", consider "*sing", which would match "arousing", "carousing", etc.  Or, "ba*ed", which would match "baked", "banked", or "balanced".

Comment: First off, `spo?ls` matches `ls` *or* `spols`. Are you saying you want to parse a string that includes a `?` and have it mean something else when creating a RegExp from that string, or what are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: Are you looking for allowing 1 random characters or infinite random characters?

Comment: @tenub No, it matches `spols` or `spls`. `?` only applies to the `o`.

Comment: @tenub: He's using the `*` and `?` as wildcards.  He wants to "convert" them to a regex.  It's common to have `*` mean "any number of characters", and `?` mean "one character".

Comment: This post seems to be getting downvotes from people who haven't read the question - the OP isn't describing regex, he's describing standard wildcards, and looking for a regex conversion. Please read the question before trying to correct the OP.

Comment: simple conversion: * = .*  ,  ? = .

Answer (score 3):

Roughly:

- `*` → `.*` (any character, zero or more)
- `?` → `.` (any character, exactly one)

You'll also need to ignore case (with the `i` flag) and ensure nothing else matches (with anchors), e.g.:

- `spo?ls` → `/^spo.ls$/i`

Whatever, I recommend you learn some basics about regular expressions. The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is quite good.

P.S. The `.` metacharacter does not match new lines.

Comment: Don't you mean `/^spo.?ls$/i` here?

Comment: @nrabinowitz - Thank you for spotting the typo.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't what `?` does. `?` is a quantifier, **not** a wild card.

If you want to match any single character, you need `.`.

In your case, you can replace all instances of `?` with `.`, and then pass the string to `RegExp`:

```
pattern = "spo?ls";

// produces /spo.ls/
regex = RegExp(pattern.replace(/\?/g, '.'));
```

Ditto `*`: It's a quantifier, *not* a wild card. You can do the same for `*`, except you'd replace all instances of `*` with `.*`.

Answer (score 1):

In regex the period (`.`) is used to match "any character".

So you could "convert" `"spo?ls"` to `/spo.ls/`.

If you wanted the `.` to possibly match 0 characters, you could use `/spo.?ls/`.  The `?` means "0 or 1 character".

In regex, the `*` character means "0 or more", and `+` means 1 or more.

So depending on what you were looking for, `"spo*ls"` could be converted to `/spo.+ls/` or `/spo.*ls/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = 'spo?ls';
if (string.indexOf('?') !== -1) string = string.replace('?', '[a-zA-Z]');
if (string.indexOf('*') !== -1) string = string.replace('*', '[a-zA-Z]+');
var dictionary = ['spoils', 'spools', 'spoools', 'fools', 'tools'];
var re = new RegExp('^' + string + '$');
var results = dictionary.filter(function(el) {
    return (el.match(re) !== null);
});

console.log(results);
["spoils", "spools"];
```

Now try with `string = 'spo*ls';`

```
console.log(results);
["spoils", "spools", "spoools"];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Pattern tokenpattern = Pattern.compile("string you get");
Matcher matcher = tokenpattern.matcher(content to check);
matcher.find();
```

Is this the answer to your question?

As i can see the String you get is already the RegularExpression and you just have to use it as one.

Lg Teifun2